# Is it possible to export a state value from inside a hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following hook:

```
const useAuth = () => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({
    isAuthenticated: false,
    accountType: 'anonymous',
    userId: '',
    email: ''
  });

  const signIn = () => {
    // Do something...

    setAuth({
      isAuthenticated: true,
      accountType: 'email',
      userId: 'abc123',
      email: 'foo@bar.com'
    });
  }


  return {
    signIn,
    auth
  };
};

export default useAuth;
```

As you can see I'm exporting the `auth` state value, but it doesn't seem to be working. In the component I'm using this hook the value for `auth` is the original:

```
{
  isAuthenticated: false,
  accountType: 'anonymous',
  userId: '',
  email: ''
}
```

Even if I call the `signIn()` method which should update this value to:

```
{
  isAuthenticated: true,
  accountType: 'email',
  userId: 'abc123',
  email: 'foo@bar.com'
}
```

The updated value doesn't reach the component using the hook (even though it successfully updates the state value inside the hook), how to get the updated value in the component using the hook?

Comment: How are you checking the value of `auth` after calling `signIn()`? Since `setAuth()` (which is called inside of signIn) can be asynchronous, you may be logging the `auth` before it has been updated?

Comment: To confirm that `auth` is successfully being updated after calling `signIn()` I have `  useEffect(() => { console.log('[auth updated]', auth); }, [auth]);` inside the hook. I'm just looking at the last console log.

Comment: And in the component using the hook I have `const { auth, signIn } = useAuth();` and using `auth` as the value of a context provider. I don't see the updated value in react-devtools context viewer and I also console log `auth` in the render and don't see any re-renders after the value is updated.

Comment: you talk about some auth context provider. sounds like you have two independent `auth` states.

Comment: I'm using the `auth` state value from the hook as the value of the auth context. The hook manages the context's value.